# Div background with flash object

Tags: html, css, background, flash

http://www.unshoolme.org/gamesi/games/kingdom-rush.html

Hey guys, so the background to my content div(the middle part with the flash file) I found doesn't completely cover everything that I want it to, so it makes the the flash file stick out and be....you know..awkward. I've tried many things in my css which is right here...

http://www.unschoolme.org/gamesi/games/css/style.css

Meanwhile, I also have a header and footer.

unschoolme.org/games/header.shtml

and

unschoolme.org/games/footer.shtml

Any help and suggestions is much appreciated, and I don't mind if I have to change the arrangement of everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
#contents ul.images {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto 15px;
width: 632px;
}
```

to

```
#contents ul.images {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto 15px -42px;
width: 632px;
}
```

That wil fix your issue

Comment: Thanks so much! But, is there any possible way to add some padding to make it so the white and gray part go over to the right more?

Comment: That white part is an image i think. U will have to check

` #page {
    background: url("../images/bg-page.jpg") repeat scroll left top transparent;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}`
and make the changes based on this.